VisualStateManager in DataTemplate created by code
I have the following code:
MainPage.xml
<ContentPage x:Class="Test1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
    Title="MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultItemTemplate">
            <Border Stroke="Transparent" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 4" 
                MinimumWidthRequest="36" MinimumHeightRequest="36">

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Index" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                <Label x:Name="Index" Text="X" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />

            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout Padding="16" Spacing="12">

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="1"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="Check1" CheckedChanged="Check1_CheckedChanged"/>
            <ContentView x:Name="ContentView1"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="2"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="Check2" CheckedChanged="Check2_CheckedChanged"/>
            <ContentView x:Name="ContentView2"/>
        </StackLayout>
                
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

MainPage.xaml.cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shapes;

namespace Test1;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {

    View view1;
    View view2;
    
    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Taked from xaml resource
        view1 = (View)((DataTemplate)Resources["DefaultItemTemplate"]).CreateContent();
        ContentView1.Content = view1;
        
        //Created by code
        view2 = (View)DefaultItemTemplate.CreateContent();
        ContentView2.Content = view2;


    }


    private void Check1_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(view1, e.Value ? "Selected" : "Normal");

            var asd = view1.FindByName("Index");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(asd ?? "null"); // works ok, it gets the label
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}"); 
        }
    }

    private void Check2_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(view2, e.Value ? "Selected" : "Normal");

            var asd = view2.FindByName("Index");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(asd ?? "null"); // returns null, label not found??
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}"); 
        }
    }

    private static DataTemplate DefaultItemTemplate => new DataTemplate( () => {
        var view = new Border() {
            Stroke = Colors.Transparent,
            BackgroundColor = Colors.WhiteSmoke,
            StrokeShape = new RoundRectangle { CornerRadius = 4 },
            MinimumWidthRequest = 36,
            MinimumHeightRequest = 36,
        };

        var label = new Label() {
            StyleId = "Index", // it doenst work
            Text = "X",
            TextColor = Colors.Black,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
        view.Content = label;

        var commonStateGoup = new VisualStateGroup { Name = "CommonStates" };
        var stateNormal = new VisualState { Name = "Normal" };
        var stateSelected = new VisualState { Name = "Selected" };

        stateSelected.Setters.Add(new Setter {
            Property = BackgroundColorProperty,
            Value = Application.Current!.Resources.TryGetValue("Primary",out var primaryColor) ? (Color)primaryColor : Colors.BlueViolet,
        });
        // Commenting this works, but label is not affected. Else 
        /*
        stateSelected.Setters.Add(new Setter {
            TargetName =  "Index", // doesnt work
            Property = Label.TextColorProperty,
            Value = Colors.White,
        });
        */
        commonStateGoup.States.Add(stateNormal);
        commonStateGoup.States.Add(stateSelected);

        VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(view).Add(commonStateGoup);

        return view;
    });
}

what im trying to achieve is to create the DefaultItemTemplate from the xaml resource but by code, and currently i cant make the VisualStateManager target the Label. It works as expected if i take the template from the xaml page resource, but not from de code behind.
How can i make it work?

It relates to the known issue on GitHub, Using TargetName reference in VisualStates in MAUI in C# (NOT Xaml).  But you may also try using data binding as a workaround.

@LiqunShen-MSFT omg inside that post i could find the answer that get it work... tnx man

So glad it helps and thanks for your sharing! You may follow up this issue and get the latest updates. Hope it can be fixed asap! BTW binding to IsChecked property may also work for this scenario.

Thanks to the link posted in comments by Liqun Shen-MSFT, i could get it work. Here is the DataTemplate code:
private static DataTemplate DefaultItemTemplate => new( () => {
    var view = new Border() {
        Stroke = Colors.Transparent,
        StrokeThickness = 4d,
        BackgroundColor = Colors.WhiteSmoke,
        StrokeShape = new RoundRectangle { CornerRadius = 4 },
        MinimumWidthRequest = 36,
        MinimumHeightRequest = 36,
    };
    var label = new Label() {
        Text = "-",
        TextColor = Colors.Black,
        FontSize = 14,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    };
    view.Content = label;

    // using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals;
    // this make the magic, you need to set the namescope and register the name this way
    INameScope nameScope = new NameScope();
    NameScope.SetNameScope(view, nameScope);
    //nameScope.RegisterName("Root", view);
    nameScope.RegisterName("Index", label);


    var commonStateGoup = new VisualStateGroup { Name = "CommonStates" };
    var stateNormal = new VisualState { Name = "Normal" };
    var stateSelected = new VisualState { Name = "Selected" };

    stateNormal.Setters.Add(new());

    stateSelected.Setters.Add(new Setter {
        //TargetName = "Root",
        Property = BackgroundColorProperty,
        Value = Application.Current!.Resources.TryGetValue("Primary",out var primaryColor) ? (Color)primaryColor : Colors.BlueViolet,
    });
    stateSelected.Setters.Add(new Setter {
        TargetName =  "Index",
        Property = Label.TextColorProperty,
        Value = Colors.White,
    });

    commonStateGoup.States.Add(stateNormal);
    commonStateGoup.States.Add(stateSelected);

    VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(view).Add(commonStateGoup);

    return view;
});

